# making description field link to original content through view in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

i have created a taxonomy vocabulary and added few word with description. Now I'm displaying taxonomy term and its description through view module using grid format. I want to make description field to link to its original taxonomy term page. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps:

1. Add a field "Term ID" and do a "Exclude from Display" on it. Make sure this precedes the description field in the views.
2. Click on the description field in the view, and go to the section "Rewrite Results"
3. Check the checkbox "Output this field as a link". Check the replacement pattern for the term id. Usually it will be something like this [term-id].
4. In the Link Path, construct the url like this: taxonomy/term/[term-id]

Please let me know if you find any issues.